# Como fazer o Git aceitar outro usuário?

Tags: git, github

Preciso de ajuda para resolver um problema que está ocorrendo em meu Git.

Vou especificar o passo a passo de tudo que ocorreu desde o início.

Como meu gráfico de contribuições não estava mais mostrando meus commits e eu estava commitando com nome e e-mail corretos, resolvi abrir outro GitHub e o cadastrei no git.

Depois, sempre ficava dando erro e mesmo que eu fizesse login, não conseguia enviar nada para meu GitHub qualquer que fosse ele. Descobri, pesquisando, que eu coloquei dois usuários em uma chave SSH.

Não conseguindo resolver, excluí meus dois GitHubs, desinstalei o git e instalei para a nova versão. Mas ainda continua dando erro.

Meu perfil antigo do GitHub estava com o usuário PatriciaBerzin e meu perfil novo do GitHub, hoje aberto, está com o usuário patiberzin. Como eu excluí o PatriciaBerzin e só tenho o pati, quero continuar com este.

Meu computador é Windows, eu uso o Git Bash. Não entendo de muita coisa, só o básico que eu conseguia enviar meus trabalhos em HTML e CSS para os repositórios. Então peço que a resposta seja bem especificada.

Se alguém puder me ajudar a configurar esse novo usuário e e-mail para que ele aceite e esqueça o outro, agradeço muito, porque até hoje de manhã eu tinha portfólio, agora ele está somente no meu computador. T_T

Obs: Antes de reinstalar o Git eu fiz o seguinte passo e não deu certo:

```
git config --global --unset-all user.name "PatriciaBerzin"
git config --global --add user.name "patiberzin"
```

e

```
git config --global --unset-all user.email "e-mail antigo"
git config --global --add user.email "novo e-mail"
```

Comment: Desde agosto a política de acesso ao git mudou. Agora você precisa criar um token pessoal: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Para entender, basta ter paciência de ler. Eu também já coloquei a solução. Além disso, a pergunta é clara "Como fazer o Git aceitar outro usuário?". Na minha resposta eu informo que como não consegui que ele aceitasse outro usuário, tive que excluir todas as configurações do git e criar novas.

Answer (score 0):

> No processo, eu acabei excluindo o GitHub antigo e criei um novo e
> reinstalei o Git com a versão mais recente. Também acabei criando um
> Token e uma chave SHA.

Como resolvi o meu problema:

Removi o usuário colocando no Git:

```
$ git config --global --remove-section user
```

Inseri senha, no meu caso pediu o token que eu tinha criado. Mas se você não gerou token, coloque sua senha.

**Setei a URL de cada pasta no meu computador.** Em cada pasta que haviam os arquivos dos meus projetos. **Basta escrever no Git:**
$ git remote set-url origin urlnova

E dei o push para testar.